# How should I deal with C# to JSON Serialization and circular references?

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization

I am using the System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer contained in System.Web.Extentions DLL. I have several circular references such as a basic many-to-many relationship and a parent-child relationship. How can I deal with these? One idea we had was to replace actual object references with Foreign Keys. For example, instead of this:

```
public class Node {
  public Node Parent { get; set; }
  public ICollection<Node> Children { get; set; }
}
```

We would do this:

```
public class Node {
  public long ParentID { get; set; }
  public ICollection<long> ChildrenIDs { get; set; }
}
```

I thought about using the ScriptIgnore Attribute but how do you even use that with Many-to-Many relationships? Advice and suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: Here are some example classes for the Many-to-Many Relationship.

```
public class Student {
  public long StudentID { get; private set; }
  public ICollection<Class> Classes { get; set; }
}

public class Class { 
  public long ClassID { get; private set; }
  public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Json.NET was exactly what I was looking for. Another option, though, is to create an anonymous type and serialize that.

Answer (score 3):

The usual approach is to use [ScriptIgnore] with the parent node reference like:

```
public class Node {
  [ScriptIgnore]
  public Node Parent { get; set; }    
  public ICollection<Node> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How would I do this with something like a Many-To-Many relationship?

Comment: For that, you'll have to use Json.NET. The latest version of it supports serializing circular n-to-n relationships. Check out [Preserving Object References](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/PreserveObjectReferences.html) in the help.